# How to reproject shapefile using ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr, ogr2ogr

I have shapefile in EPSG:2834 and I want to reproject it into EPSG:4326. I am trying to use `ogr2ogr` in Windows; however, I get this failure output:

```
C:\Users\Nik\Desktop\Logan_Lines>ogr2ogr -t_srs epsg:4326 spans_4326 spans
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `spans' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> SDTS
  -> TIGER
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> NAS
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> Interlis 1
  -> Interlis 2
  -> GMT
  -> SQLite
  -> ODBC
  -> PGeo
  -> OGDI
  -> PostgreSQL
  -> MySQL
  -> XPlane
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
  -> DXF
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK

C:\Users\Nik\Desktop\Logan_Lines>
```

I am hoping someone can tell me what I am doing wrong; I have little experience with this tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All that's happening, as far as I can see, is that it cannot find a file called `spans`. Make sure you provide the path to the file (either relative or absolute), and add the extension, which will be `.shp` in this case.

If you're still having problems, then it might be that you have a broken Shapefile, see if you can get useful information from `ogrinfo`, and try loading it into a GIS such as Quantum GIS.

Comment: If the source file has no extension, you have to tell ogr2ogr which driver to use with `-f "ESRI Shapefile" `.